# Finding the probability of a given group being selected

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a set of $n$ people, each with probability $p(i)$ of being selected in a random draw. Suppose that we are to select $k$ winners without replacement according to such probabilities. Is there a "simple" expression that yields the probability that a given group (i.e., $\{i_{1}, \dots, i_{k}\}$) is selected?

For example, if $n=4$ and $k=2$, the probability of selecting the group $\{1, 2\}$ as the winner group is:

$P(1)*P(2|1)+P(2)*P(1|2)$, where $P(1|2)$ is the probability that 1 is selected in the second draw, given that 2 was selected in the first draw. Here, the first term accounts for the possibility of 1 being drawn first and 2 second. Similarly, the second term accounts for 2 being drawn first, and 1 second.

This idea can be extended for larger values of $k$. However, the problem is that the drawing order must be considered, which means that you need to take into account the permutations of the given group. For example, for $k=3$, to calculate the probability that group $\{1,2,3\}$ is selected, you need to take into account all six potential drawing sequences (i.e., (1,2,3), (1,3,2), ...(3,2,1)).

Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this calculation?

Comment: When you say "each with probability $p(i)$ of being selected in a random draw", do you mean that the $i$-th player is extracted with probability $p(i)$?

Comment: Im not sure whether I understand you correctly. $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is the number of all $k$ element subsets of a $n$ element set. So each subset has the probability $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you are just after $\prod_{i\in G}p_i\times \prod_{j\notin G}(1-p_j)$, but I am not sure.

Comment: the_candyman. Yes, what I mean is that each element has a probability $p(i)$ of being selected.

Comment: The problem with the question is that dependence is not clear.  My answer is correct if each person is selected, or not, independently of the others.  But is that what you intended?

Comment: lulu. Not really, What I want is a simple way to calculate the probability of a specific group of elements based on the fact of each element has its own probability of being selected as part of the group. In that sense, I believe your expression represents something different.

Comment: Ok, but you haven't given us any idea of why my answer is wrong.  My model is simple:  in a given selection we pass over each member of the group and choose member $i$ with probability $p_i$ independently of all other choices.  If you want some other model, you have to give us more information.

Comment: Lulu, Suppose I have a set of 4 elements $\{1,2,3,4\}$, each one has a probability (i.e., $p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4)$. For calculating the probability of the group formed by elements 1 and 2, I should use the formula presented before, $p(1)*p(2|1)+p(2)*p(1|2) $.

Comment: Sorry, I simply don't understand what you are doing.  Don't think I'm helping so I'll stop writing.

Comment: The problem is when the size of the set of elements and the size of the group to be selected are bigger. For example, with the same set of elements, I want groups of size 3, i.e. $\{1,2,3\}$,$\{1,2,4\}$,$\{2,3,4\}$,$\{1,3,4\}$, if I want to calculate the probability of group $\{1,2,3\}$, it will be: $p(\{1,2,3\})=p(1)*p(2|1)*p(3|2,1)+p(1)*p(3|1)*p(2|3,1)+p(2)*p(1|2)*p(3|2,1)+p(2)*p(3|2)*p(1|2,3)+p(3)*p(1|3)*p(2|3,1)+p(3)*p(2|3)*p(1|3,2)$. Basically, what I am looking for is a formula to calculate $p(g)$ as a function of the set of elements, $p(i)$ and g. Where g is the group of elements

Comment: S. M. Roch, that would be true if the elements are Equally likely (i.e., p(i)=p(j)).

Comment: Things could simplify if the probability of selecting person $3$ in the third trial given that person $1$ and $2$ have been selected in the first two trials does NOT depend on whether person $1$ or person $2$ has been selected first. (And this would be the situation in a random draw.) Otherwise, your problem is as general as it gets.